# What is the minimal way of defining a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

I want to define a vector space using other algebraic objects so that I don't have to list all the axioms. For example an $F$-Module, where is $F$ is a field is almost the definition of vector space. However, how could I define it using maybe algebras, modules, rings or groups(or other algebraic objects).

Comment: When $F$ is a field, $F$ vector spaces and $F$-modules are really the same (not "almost")

Comment: As said above, if $F$ is a field, an $F$-module is *exactly* the same as a vector space over $F$. Recall that if $G$ is an abelian group, the set $\operatorname{End}_\textsf{Ab}(G)$ of all group homomorphisms $G \to G$ is a ring with the pointwise addition and composition as multiplication. Thus, here is another option: If $R$ is ring, an $R$-module is an abelian group $M$ together with a ring homomorphism $R \to \operatorname{End}_\textsf{Ab}(M)$, denoted by $r \mapsto (x \mapsto rx)$.